# Creating a configurable standalone (Without a module) service in Angular 15?

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection

[We can configure Angular service using an injection token like this](https://fireflysemantics.medium.com/creating-an-injectiontoken-configurable-angular-service-d569cd4847d6).  However it uses a Module with Providers approach to inject the configuration.  Is there a way to configure services without using modules in Angular 15?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its really straight foward actually :

- provide the token
- provide the service
- inject the service

Example:

```
// define the token
const token = new InjectionToken<string>('token');

// define a service depending on the token 
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  // the token gets injected into the service
  constructor(@Inject(token) private token: string) {}

  getValue(): string {
    return this.token;
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  standalone: true,
  providers: [
    // provide token & service
    { provide: token, useValue: 'foobar'},
    MyService, 
  ],
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  constructor(myService: MyService) {
    // enjoy
    console.log(myService.getValue());
  }
}

bootstrapApplication(App);
```

Comment: Wow!!  Straight up goodness!!  Thank you - That's really cool!!